# Why are the "five afflictions" applied to Tish'a B'Av?

Tags: fast-days

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88525/5275) explains how the 5 forms of affliction are derived. I understand that on Yom Kippur, the Torah specifically says that we should afflict ourselves.

WHy are these 5 afflictions applied to Tish'a B'Av? Or, a reverse question, perhaps, why are they **not** applied to any of the other fast days except for Tish'a B'Av (and Yom Kippur, which was answered, already)?

Comment: They do apply to other major fast days for droughts

Comment: Remember all the extra stuff on Tisha Bav (beyond the regular fast day prohibition on eating) applies to Shiva mourning too. Cf. _What hath Brisk wrought?_

Comment: See Mishna Berura 550:6 They never accepted all of the afflictions on the other fasts (beside 9 Av) as that would be too difficult for most people. Nevertheless a בעל נפש should indeed keep all the afflictions (with certain exceptions) on all fasts.

Comment: I’m not sure if this fully answers your question as it doesn’t explain precisely why they accepted the afflictions on 9 Av and not the others (although I can conjecture). If you’re satisfied though let me know and I’ll post later as an answer

Comment: Rabbinic fast days such as Tisha B'Av and fasts for droughts, are enacted enacted decrees of the courts as similar to Yom Kippur including starting by sunset the night before and the 5 inuyim.  The other fasts we keep today are just a later (binding) custom, which only includes what actually became customary (i.e. only daytime fasting).